# Approximating the Lebesgue measure on the full real line with discrete measures

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, lp-spaces

For any $L>0$, let $\mu_L$ be the real Borel measure defined as follows:

$$
\mu_L=\frac{1}{L}\sum_{x\in\mathbb Z}\delta_{x/L},$$

$\delta_{x}$ being the atomic (Dirac) measure on $x$, and let $L^p(\mathbb R,\mu_L)$ the space of $p$-integrable complex-valued functions on the real line. By construction, for any $u$ in this space, we have
$$
\int_\mathbb{R}|u|^p\;\mathrm{d}\mu_L=\frac{1}{L}\sum_{x\in\mathbb{Z}}\left|u\left(\frac{x}{L}\right)\right|^p.$$

Spaces with different values of $L$ are isometric, as can be readily proven by dilation.

Now, the measure $\mu_L$ seems to "approach" the Lebesgue measure on the real line as $L$ becomes large: indeed, the integral above becomes a (improper) Riemann sum for $u$.

Does $\mu_L$ converge to the Lebesgue measure in some sense (e.g. weakly with respect to a space of suitably well-behaved functions)? I do have seen similar questions around for probability measures, but I do not know if such proofs can be extended for the Lebesgue measure on the full line.

Besides, if so, are $L^p(\mathbb{R},\mu_L)$ and $L^p(\mathbb{R})$  (the latter to be intended as the space of $p$-integrable functions with respect to the Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R}$) isometric?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't know if this is relevant for whatever sense of convergence there might be here, but note that $\mu_L(\Bbb Q)=\infty$ for all $L$, while $\Bbb Q$ is a null set for the Lebesgue measure.

Comment: @Christoph: That's only true if $L$ is rational.

Comment: @MarsPlastic You are right. I was assuming we are considering just the sequence $\mu_1,\mu_2,\dots$ for some reason. Considering the whole family for real $L>0$ is a different story. Thanks for your reply!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, weak convergence is usually only defined for finite measures (of the same total mass). But for any compact set $K\subset\mathbb R$, it is indeed true that $\mu_L(\,\cdot\,\cap K)$ converges weakly to $\lambda(\,\cdot\,\cap K)$: If $f\colon K\to \mathbb R$ is continuous, $\int_K f d\mu_L$ is a corresponding Riemann sum.

Consequently, you have $\int_{\mathbb R} f d\mu_L \to \int_{\mathbb R} f d\lambda$ for all continuous functions $f\colon\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ with compact support.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Interestingly, the space of continuous, compactly supported functions is dense in $L^p(\mathbb{R})$, implying that, via a diagonal argument, one should be able to prove that there exist sequences $(f_n)$ and $(L_n)$, with $L_n\to\infty$, such that $\|f\|^2=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{L_n}\sum_k\left|f\left(\frac{k}{L_n}\right)\right|^2$. Maybe this can be worked out to establish an isometry between $L^p(\mathbb{R},\mu_L)$ and $L^p(\mathbb{R})$.